# Хранимые процедуры vs. Запросы

Tags: sql, sql-server

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что можно сделать?
Хранимая процедура выполняется дольше чем если запустить весь код в ней.
Заранее спасибо

Comment: [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?](https://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html) Есть перевод статьи на русский

Comment: [Why is my query suddenly slower than it was yesterday?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/204565/why-is-my-query-suddenly-slower-than-it-was-yesterday/)

Answer (score 1):

Сделай объявление переменных в самой процедуре, передавай в них входящие значение и используй эти переменные в самом запросе процедуры.

Проблема известна как [Parameter sniffing](https://habr.com/ru/post/109580/)